# Retrieve one row from SQL Server to Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using this code to search data in SQL Server. But the result is return to list, what should I return it to get one row only? Means I want to use textblock binding to get a record without using listbox template..

```
public List<Customer> FindProfile(string custemail)
{
    var findprofile = from r in cust.Customers where r.CustEmail == custemail select r;
    return findprofile.ToList();
}

public List<Customer> GetProfileData()
{
    var profiledata = from r in cust.Customers
                      select r;
    return profiledata.Take(5).ToList();
}

public pgProfile()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   proxy.FindProfileCompleted += new EventHandler<FindProfileCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_FindProfileCompleted);
   proxy.FindProfileAsync(custemail);
}

void proxy_FindProfileCompleted(object sender, FindProfileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` on the list of customers that gets returned??

```
List<Customer> customers = GetProfileData();

// get just the first customer:
Customer first = customers.First();
```

Comment: @ marc_s Thnx.but i dont want use the listbox template.Is it textblock can binding without listbox template?

Comment: @Brownieyeo: well, now that you have a single `Customer` - you should be able to bind that to a textblock - no??

Comment: i forget to add void proxy.. then what should i put instead of lisbox1.ItemSource = e.Result;

Comment: @Brownieyeo: that's a totally separate question - this one was about getting one row from SQL Server - that's been answered. Please put your other problem into a separate WPF question